# How to write a functional test with user authentication?

Tags: testing, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, functional-testing

I am writing a functional test for a page that requires user authentication. I am using the sfDoctrineGuard plugin.

How do I authenticate a user in my test?

Do I have to enter every test through the sign in screen?

Here is my incorrect code:

```
$b->post('/sfGuardAuth/signin',
       array('signin[password]' => 'password',
             'signin[username]' => 'user',
             'signin[_csrf_token]' => '7bd809388ed8bf763fc5fccc255d042e'))->
       with('response')->begin()->
         checkElement('h2', 'Welcome Humans')->
       end()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do have to sign in to carry out tests.  Fortunately, this is much simpler than the method you illustrate above.  See the "better and simpler way" [on this blog post](http://sandbox-ws.com/frameworks/symfony-frameworks/functional-testing-a-secured-module).

You could make the `signin` method part of any `TestFunctional` class according to how you've structured your tests.

Comment: the page doesn't exists anymor, but here is another way of doing [tests for loggin] (http://snipplr.com/view/27686/)

Answer (score 6):

The tricky part about doing a signin is that the test browser wipes out the context object before each request (see [sfBrowser::call()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/blob/v1.4.16/lib/util/sfBrowser.class.php#L32)).

You can authenticate the user by injecting a listener which will call the user's `signIn()` method when the `context.load_factories` event fires during context initialization:

```
function signin( sfEvent $event )
{
  /* @var $user sfGuardSecurityUser */
  if( ! $user = $event->getSubject()->getUser() )
  {
    throw new RuntimeException('User object not created.');
  }

  if( ! $user instanceof sfGuardSecurityUser )
  {
    throw new LogicException(sprintf(
      'Cannot log in %s; sfGuardSecurityUser expected.',
        get_class($user)
    ));
  }

  if( $user->isAuthenticated() )
  {
    $user->signOut();
  }

  /* Magic happens here: */
  $user->signIn($desired_user_to_log_in_as);

  $event->getSubject()->getEventDispatcher()->notify(new sfEvent(
    $this,
    'application.log',
    array(sprintf('User is logged in as "%s".', $user->getUsername()))
  ));
}

/* Set signin() to fire when the browser inits the context for subsequent
 *  requests.
 */
$b->addListener('context.load_factories', 'signin');
```

This will cause the browser to sign in the user for *all* subsequent requests.  Note that `sfBrowser` does *not* have a `removeListener()` method.

Adapted from [sfJwtPhpUnitPlugin](https://github.com/JWT-OSS/sfJwtPhpUnitPlugin/blob/1.0.8/lib/test/Browser/Listener/Signin.class.php) (FD: I'm the lead dev for this project).

Comment: Amazing!
Just want to say, when signin method defined in some child class of sfTestFunctional, a listener attachment must be called like this $b->addListener('context.load_factories', array($b, 'signin'));

Comment: I needed to force signin later in the symfony bootstrap process because my app's myUser depends on the route. So I used $b->addListener('controller.change_action', 'signin') instead.